# Curl error 35 SSL Connect error in php

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Am using CURL to get the XML response in PHP. The problem is when I run the PHP cron job file, It didn't get the response.

```
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);

$responseAll = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I run the CURL in command prompt I get the response

```
CURL -Li <URL>
```

But the problem is when I run this as a PHP file, the curl throws the error as

> 35 SSL Connect error

*Note:* Also the same works fine in PHP4. The problem occurs only in PHP5

Comment: Related: [curl errno 35 (Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to \[secure site\]:443)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073404/curl-errno-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-to-secure-site443) -  Please report this back to the administrator of your server. There might be a problem with the SSL libraries used by the curl bindings in PHP. If you google for the curl error number you see a lot of system-configuration related threads. This can not be easily solved with passing an options or writing a line of PHP code.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://matt.thomm.es/archive/2012/10/26/php-curl-error-ssl-connect-error At least it helped me to fight the same problem, if this is the solution, I can make it an answer to accept.